# steady state errors of a control system

Tags: control-theory

I was reading that for a type-2 system the value of acceleration constant
$$K_a = \omega^2$$ where $\omega$ is the gain cross over frequency. This means that the units for $K_a$ should be $(\frac{rad}{sec})^2$. But I found in the datasheet of AD2s83 that the units for acceleration constant are defined as $(\frac{1}{sec})^2$. There seems to be some conflict in the units. Clarifications are required in this regard.

Comment: Radians are dimensionless. Therefore angular velocity and angular acceleration are often denoted as $1/s$ and $1/s^2$ respectively. But yes, if the angular velocity is like $\pi/s$, then the acceleration constant should be $\pi^2/s^2$. So check if the datasheet does that correctly.

Comment: See AD2S83 datasheet p.15 , they seem to be analyzing Ka in degrees/sec^2 . This is actually a somewhat complex product, looks like a PLL in there

Comment: for a servo system which is primarily rotational in nature, radians should appear in the units for acceleration constant. But I do not find this in textbooks. it is apparent that the value of acceleration constant is square of gain cross over frequency , where x-axis is defined in rad/s. Hence I am not very clear about this concept.